# $\mathbb{E}\left(\mathbb{E}\left(y|x\right)|x\right)=\mathbb{E}\left(y|x\right)$

Tags: probability, expectation

Why

$$\mathbb{E}\left(\mathbb{E}\left(y|x\right)|x\right)=\mathbb{E}\left(y|x\right)?$$

Here is what I managed to do:

$$\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}\left(y|x\right)|x\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\int yf\left(y|x\right)dy\,|\,x\right]=\int\int yf\left(y|x\right)dy\,f\left(?|x\right)dy=...=\int yf\left(y|x\right)dy$$

As you can see, I don't know what to put instead of the question mark, then, I don't see how this double integral will simplify to the expected result.

Comment: Are you familiar with [conditional expectations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_a_random_variable) w.r.t. random variables?

Comment: @drhab, I used to think that I am, but since yesterday I have doubts.

Comment: Don't despair. It is about the function $m(x)=\mathbb E(y\mid x)$ mentioned in Theorem 2.32.1 in the link you gave. There you read that this function must meet the condition $\mathbb E(1(x\in\chi)y)=\mathbb E(1(x\in\chi)m(x)$ for measurable sets $\chi$. The essence of my answer is that - if $y=f(x)$ - then $m(x):=f(x)$ satisfies these conditions. I feel obliged to encourage you to get hold of this without appealing any integrations. But of course you are a free man :-).

Comment: @drhab, first, thank you for taking time and looking in the book. OK, but how Hansen managed to prove that theorem 2.7.2 using integrals? spaceisdarkgreen says that Hansen's proof is wrong. Whom should I believe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\mathbb E(y\mid x)$ is a random variable that is measurable wrt the $\sigma$-algebra generated by random variable $x$.

For *every* random variable $z$ that is measurable wrt the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $x$ we have: $$\mathbb E(z\mid x)=z$$

So also: $$\mathbb E(\mathbb E(y\mid x)\mid x)=\mathbb E(y\mid x)$$

---

**edit** (without using the words "algebra" and "measurable").

A "suitable" function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ exists such that $\mathbb E(y\mid x)=f(x)$

For every "suitable" function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ we have:$$\mathbb E(f(x)\mid x)=f(x)$$

So also: $$\mathbb E(\mathbb E(y\mid x)\mid x)=\mathbb E(f(x)\mid x)=f(x)=\mathbb E(y\mid x)$$

Actually "suitable" is "Borel-measurable" in this context, but that term was contaminated.

---

**edit2**

Let $X,Y,Z$ be random variables defined on the same probability space.

If the function $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ prescribed by $x\mapsto\mathbb E(Z\mid X=x)$ is denoted by $f$ then $\mathbb E(Z\mid X)$ is a notation for random variable $f(X)$.

Now observe what happens if $Z=g(X)$ for some function $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$.

Then $f(x)=\mathbb E(g(X)\mid X=x)=g(x)$.

So $\mathbb E(g(X)\mid X)$ is actually a notation for $f(X)=g(X)$ or more succinctly:$$\mathbb E(g(X)\mid X)=g(X)\tag1$$

If $Z=\mathbb E(Y\mid X)$ then indeed $Z=g(X)$ for some function $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$.

So application of $(1)$ results in:$$\mathbb E(\mathbb E(Y\mid X) \mid X)=\mathbb E(g(X)\mid X)=g(X)=\mathbb E(Y\mid X)$$

Comment: Could you please explain without using words algebra and measurable?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, thought I still don't understand it. Is there a way to show it via integrals?

Comment: @John in order to do it "with integrals" you would need to integrate against the conditional distribution of $E(Y|X)$ conditioned on $X$. Something like $\int \,zf_{z|x}(z|x)dz$ where $Z=E(Y|X)$. However $E(Y|X)$ is a random variable that is a function of $X$ (i.e. "measurable wrt the sigma algebra generated by $X$") so it doesn't have a conditional PDF when conditioned on $X$... it becomes a constant. Think about computing the the conditional expectation $E(X^2|X).$ What do you get? Can you do it "with integrals"? (Or is it productive to do so, anyway?) The principal here is exactly the same.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen, I would appreciate if someone could show me using integrals.

Comment: @John Lol no. Do $E(X^2|X)$ using integrals. It will be enlightening I promise.

Comment: I could give you another example where I understand the derivation: $\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}\left(y|x_{1},x_{2}\right)|x_{1}\right]=\int\mathbb{E}\left(y|x_{1},x_{2}\right)\,f\left(x_{2}|x_{1}\right)dx_{2}=\int\int yf\left(y|x_{1},x_{2}\right)dy\,f\left(x_{2}|x_{1}\right)dx_{2}=\int\int yf\left(y|x_{1},x_{2}\right)\,f\left(x_{2}|x_{1}\right)dydx_{2}=\int\int y\frac{f\left(y,x_{1},x_{2}\right)}{f\left(x_{1},x_{2}\right)}\cdot\frac{f\left(x_{2},x_{1}\right)}{f\left(x_{1}\right)}dydx_{2}=\int\int y\frac{f\left(y,x_{1},x_{2}\right)}{f\left(x_{1}\right)}dydx_{2}=$ ...

Comment: ... $=\int\int yf\left(y,x_{2}|x_{1}\right)dydx_{2}=\int y\int f\left(y,x_{2}|x_{1}\right)dx_{2}dy=\int yf\left(y|x_{1}\right)dy=\mathbb{E}\left(y|x_{1}\right)$. It is correct, isn't it?

Comment: Technically, if we let $x_2 = $ constant, we would obtain the relationship I asked in my post. But I miss something.

Comment: @John You need to @ if you want me to see. And no that's not correct. It vaguely resembles something correct and gets the right answer, but the fact that it doesn't obviously specialize to what should be an easier problem shows that something is missing. Thinking about my simpler problem, or better yet investing time in learning what conditional expectation is will be more productive than mindlessly integrating. This is the last I'll reply since I don't want to cause the original answerer noise, but feel free to ask a new question if you make some progress refining it.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen, actually, it's not my proof. You could find it on page 64 in http://www.ssc.wisc.edu/~bhansen/econometrics/Econometrics.pdf

Comment: @drhab Sir, I really appreciate your efforts, but, if you read my question carefully, you might notice that I am interested in solution via integrals. It's good that there exists the easier solution, but I created this question to get specific answer.

Comment: That's okay. But why did you (uptil now) not answer my question concerning familiarity with conditional expectations?

Comment: @drhab, to be clear. I think I understand how your proof works. Intuitively, you are saying that since we know value of X=x, we know value of function f(X=x), hence, averaging (aka taking expectation) the constant changes nothing. However, I still don't get how it could be written via density. Even if we take the simplest example: $\mathbb{E}\left(x|x\right)=\int xf\left(x|x\right)dx=...$ I thought that such density should degenerate to 1 because P(X=x|X=x) = 1, but $\int xf\left(x|x\right)dx=\int x\cdot1dx=\frac{x^{2}}{2}\neq x$. What goes wrong with integrals? This is what I don't get.

Comment: I will have a look at this later. It is time for me to go to bed.

Comment: @drhab, meanwhile, I learnt about such thing as Dirak delta function, so now I think $\mathbb{E}\left(x|x\right) = \int x\cdot f\left(x|x\right)dx=\int x\cdot\delta\left(x\right)dx=x\int\delta\left(x\right)dx=x\cdot1=x$, right? If so, then, similarly, $\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}\left(y|x\right)|x\right]=\int\mathbb{E}\left(y|x\right)f\left(x|x\right)dx=\int\mathbb{E}\left(y|x\right)\delta\left(x\right)dx=\mathbb{E}\left(y|x\right)\int\delta\left(x\right)dx=\mathbb{E}\left(y|x\right)\cdot1=\mathbb{E}\left(y|x\right)$.

Comment: @John I still advocate for more understanding and less integrating, but for the purposes of making the integration approach work, you are on the right track with the delta function. But your expressions are not correct. For instance $\int x\delta(x)dx = 0,$ not $x.$ The key thing preventing you from making it work is that you need to distinguish between random variables and integration variables. So, we can write (if we must) $E(X|X=x) = \int x' f_{X|X}(x'|X=x)dx' = \int x'\delta(x'-x)dx' = x.$ Note this was lurking behind the scenes in the textbook derivation (why integrate only wrt $x_2$?)

Comment: I go along @spaceisdarkgreen. Simple proof of 2.7.2. with no integration and purely on base of 2.32.1: $\mathbb{E}\left[1_{\left\{ X_{1}\in B\right\} }\mathbb{E}\left(Y\mid X_{1},X_{2}\right)\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[1_{\left\{ \left(X_{1},X_{2}\right)\in B\times\mathbb{R}^k\right\} }\mathbb{E}\left(Y\mid X_{1},X_{2}\right)\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[1_{\left\{ \left(X_{1},X_{2}\right)\in B\times\mathbb{R}^k\right\} }Y\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[1_{\left\{ X_{1}\in B\right\} }Y\right]$.